# 39 + votes but no reputation change

Tags: support, status-completed

I have watched my reputation changes and understood every one, until today.  I answered a question this morning, received 39 votes, but no reputation change at all from that answer. I thought I understood the reputation system pretty well, including the Community Wiki exception, and the daily cap, but I'm missing something today.

Comment: Which question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Your answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/103501/thoughts-on-development-using-virtual-machines/103504#103504) was marked "community wiki". Revision history showed it was set by you 18 hours ago (as of this writing).

The best explanation I can give is that you accidentally checked the "community wiki" checkbox when making the post.

I removed the CW status and turned it into a normal answer. Visit the [reputation breakdown](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/reputation) and use the button at the bottom of the page to trigger a reputation recalc. You should get your reputation back (up to the daily cap) at that point.

Comment: Oddly enough, the revision history shows no hint of CW now. I'm asking about that on [Meta SO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103942/remove-wiki-does-not-register-in-revision-history).

Comment: Thanks Anna... accidentally checking "Community Wiki" seems the most likely explanation.